# Import Node.js app into Intellij IDEA

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I would like to import this [project](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git) into IDEA.

I downloaded the [Node.js](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6098?pr=idea_ce) plugin, version 134.680.

But when I try to install it is says:`"Plugin is incompatible with this version of IDE."`

I am running IDEA 13.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this issue the other day. The fix was to use Plugin version: 133.293  ::

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?pr=idea_ce&updateId=14820

In Ultimate edition, you can go to File -> Settings > Plugins > Click the 'Browse Repositories...' button, you should see a working version of the NodeJS plugin that you can download too. Cheers! [image]

Comment: I do not have any "node.js" result neither in the main window, nor in "browse repositories" window.

Comment: Also, when I installed version 133.293 I get an error: "Plugin "NodeJS" was not loaded: required plugin "JavaScript" not installed."

Comment: Ah, are you using IntelliJ Community Edition, per chance? I just downloaded the CE version and I experienced the same thing that you have written. On the Ultimate Edition, the NodeJS plugin appears. It seems that the IntelliJ Community Edition does not support this plugin at all.

Comment: Also experiencing this problem using either IntelliJ 12 or 13, Community or Ultimate Edition.